# What does "x" mean in the typical xstr macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, naming-conventions

It's common practice to define stringizing macros like:

```
#define str(token) #token
#define xstr(token) str(token)
```

Why is the `x` prefix typically used?  Is there any meaning to "x"?

(My guess would be that maybe it stands for "expanded" (if anything), but I have no evidence to back that up.)

Comment: It's just an uncommon character, added to make the symbol unique.

Comment: `str` would be used very frequently in source code by users, so my guess is they `#undef` it after this and use `xstr`. But no idea why the `x`.

Comment: Are you sure it's "typically used"? I've seen many other variants too (`STRIGIFY`, `STRINGIZE`, `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`).

Comment: @Groo It's used in in the [C FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html), in the [GCC docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/Stringification.html), and is referenced in [a number of StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+xstr).  While there are certainly other names, I feel like I've seen `xstr` (or some capitalized variant) more often than any of the others.

Comment: Are you asking only out of curiosity or is there something more to it?

Comment: @machine_1 I'm curious about the history behind it.

Comment: The X seems to have a tradition in preprocessor magic, see for example this piece of beauty: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro. You could certainly use any other identifier for the X macro technique, but the identifier and the resulting name sticks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have suggested, the `x` seems to be used for **extended** or I've also seen **expanded** used as well. An article on  [Stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html) by GNU has a reference to this use.

They phrase it as:

> "If you want to stringize the result [...],
>   you have to use two levels of macros."

```
#define xstr(s) str(s)
#define str(s) #s
#define foo 4
str (foo)
     → "foo"
xstr (foo)
     → xstr (4)
     → str (4)
     → "4"
```

They continue to state:

> "s is stringized when it is used in str, so it is not **macro-expanded**
>   first. But s is an ordinary argument to xstr, so it is completely
>   macro-expanded before xstr itself is expanded (see Argument Prescan).
>   Therefore, by the time str gets to its argument, it has already been
>   macro-expanded."

While none of this is concrete, I think you're safe to assume x is expanded/extended usage.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `x` in front of a macro or function call name, I use it to mean *extended* usage, and I think I am not alone.

For your example, one use `str` to stringify `token`, but should use `xstr` for extended usage, that is to expand macro argument and stringify that result.
For comparison, when just one of the macro should be used for most of the time and the other is for internal implementations, I would do like followings:

```
#define _str(token) #token
#define str(token) _str(token)
```